# Define an object of a certain class as None

Tags: python, class, pycharm

Can an object be set to `None` when initialized, but still belong to a class?

```
class Foo:
    def do_stuff():
        pass

bar_1 = Foo()
bar_2 = None
```

The specific purpose I have in mind is that I want `bar_2` to be available accross different modules, but define it at a later date (for reasons that are irrelevant). It works just fine, when you run the code. My IDE, however, does not know that `bar_2` is of type `Foo`, and hence will not show me `do_stuff()` as an autocomplete option the way it does for `bar_1`, for instance.

I understand that python is not a strongly typed language, but I reckon if there was a way to tell python that `bar_2` is of type `Foo`, it would solve the problem of autocomplete not showing up.

If there is another way to make my IDE (PyCharm, specifically) aware of `bar_2`'s class, I'd be happy to know.

Comment: What is bar2 supposed to be?

Comment: In your current code, `bar_2` is not of type `Foo`. If you want it to be `Foo`, you need to define it as such. If you need to delay initialization, create a method other than `__init__` that does the actions you wish to delay, then call it when ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.5, you can use type hinting. For this specific use, you'd need to put it in a [type comment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id33):

```
bar_2 = None # type: Foo
```

Earlier versions of Python don't have a builtin way of doing this, though I suppose an IDE that supports both earlier and later versions of the language might allow type comments to effect it's behavior even if the Python version you're using doesn't support the full type hinting semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) assuming the type is consistent and you're using python 3.5.

To get the intellisense completion JetBrains has a [legacy type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html?origin=old_help#legacy) hinting system that should work for all versions of python.

Comment: good answers :) (although the chance of him using python3.5 is slim) (I had no idea about the legacy type hinting stuff and its always cool to learn new stuff)

Answer (score 0):

when it is supposed to be an instance of foo you can do

```
assert isinstance(bar_2,Foo)
# anything below this and in scope will autocomplete bar_2 with Foo's methods
```

In general this is not a very good practice, and should be avoided but it works to enable autocomplete in *most* IDE's (pycharm included)